# Can I use colon (:) in Python to get multiple elements in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I tried the following codes to get elements of "1    46    91   136".

```
import numpy as np

x0 = np.arange(0, 180)

y0=x0[1:45:180]
```

However, `y0` is `array([1])`.

I noticed someone use the following codes: `z0=x0[0:91:90]`

This results in `array([0, 90])`. What is the meaning of using "91" which is larger that "90"?

The colon (:) is quite different to that in Matlab code. Would you please give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Syntax for array slices in Python is start:end:step, not start:step:end like MATLAB.

Therefore you want `y0=x0[1:180:45]`.

```
import numpy as np    
x0 = np.arange(0, 180)    
y0=x0[1:180:45]
print(y0)
>>> [  1  46  91 136]
```